# Error in showing error for openweathermap API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, react-router, openweathermap

I am using [openweathermap.org](http://openweathermap.org) api in my react app. Its works fine but  doesn't show error when user enters wrong city name.
also sometimes show

> cannot read property 'message' of undefined

my openweather.js

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const weather_url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=************&units=metric';

export default {
    getTemp(location){
        var encodedLocation = encodeURIComponent(location);
        var requrl = `${weather_url}&q=${encodedLocation}`;

        return axios.get(requrl).then(function(res){
            if(res.data.cod && res.data.message){
                throw new Error(res.message);
            } else{
                 return res.data.main.temp;
            }
        },function(res){
            return new Error(res.data.message);
        });
    }
}
```

react file:

```js
openWeatherMap.getTemp(location)
    .then(function(temp){
        that.setState({
            location:location,
            temp:temp,
            isLoading:false
        })
    },function(err){
        alert(err);
    });
```

Comment: @JaromandaX doesnt worked :(

Comment: @JaromandaX same error

Comment: @JaromandaX using chrome latest version .Also changing  to `return new Error(res.message);` got me 2 errors in console:`502 (Bad Gateway)` and ``Uncaught (in promise) Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Error: Request failed with status code 502). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `WeatherMessage`.

Comment: @JaromandaX same initial error :(

Comment: @JaromandaX getting error from this line : `alert(err);`

Comment: @JaromandaX when i click on bad gateway error in network tab , I got the rite results i.e. cod:502 ,message: not found city

Comment: Learn to use the dev tools.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134574/discussion-between-yash-chaudhary-and-jaromanda-x).

Comment: You need to read the [documentation for axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) regarding errors as well as the [documentation for openweathermap](http://openweathermap.org/current#parameter) regarding the format of the response. Although, it does **not** mention message, message is present at least in the error - it would be `res.response.data.message` in the error handler, by the way

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't know where you found res.response.data.message but thank you that did the trick for me! Would you mind sharing how you came up with adding the 'response' to res.data.message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a version of your code that works without any unhandled errors - based on [axios documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) and [openweathermap API documentation](http://openweathermap.org/current#parameter)

### openweather.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
const weather_url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=************&units=metric';
export default {
    getTemp(location){
        var encodedLocation = encodeURIComponent(location);
        var requrl = `${weather_url}&q=${encodedLocation}`;
        return axios.get(requrl).then(res => {
            if (res.data.cod === 200){
                return JSON.stringify(res.data);//.data.main.temp;
            }
            throw res.data.cod;
        }, res => {
            throw (res && ((res.response && res.response.data && (res.response.data.message || res.response.data)) || (res.code))) || res;
        });
    }
}
```

### react file:

```
openWeatherMap.getTemp(location).then(function(temp){
    that.setState({
        location:location,
        temp:temp,
        isLoading:false
    })
},function(err){
    alert(err);
});
```

that throw looks pretty ugly, but I don't know what type of errors you're likely to get ... that ugliness is based on errors I could "force" by various means

Comment: yea that throw looks weird but nice technique and it worked. tnx a lot!